# Pass config to a custom Ext.tree.Panel and then to a custom Ext.data.Store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How can I pass a variable to an extended `Ext.tree.Panel`, which in turn, will pass it a custom `Ext.data.Store`.

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('CustomStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    alias: 'widget.customstore',
    folderSort : true,
    model : 'TreeNode',
    autoLoad: true,
    config: {
        customParam: 'defaultVal'
    },
    ...
    proxy: {
        url: '/some/url?param'+this.customParam,
        ...
    }
});
Ext.define('CustomTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.customtree',
    config: {
        customParam2: 'defaultVal'
    },
    store: new CustomStore({customParam: this.customParam2'}),
    ...
});

var tree = Ext.create('CustomTree', {customParam2: 'someVal'});
```

As you can see, I want to pass a value `someVal` to the tree, which should pass it down to the store, the proxy of the store then needs to pick it up and use in its load url.

Tried many things, to name a few: `config`, `initConfig`, `constructor`, `initComponent` but with no good outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right ingredients but you don't mix them in the right order.

The problem here is that your store creation code:

```
new CustomStore({customParam: this.customParam2'})
```

gets called **before** the definition of `CustomTree`:

```
Ext.define('CustomTree', ...)
```

This is because `new CustomStore(...)` is used as argument to the `define` function. So, obviously, it is also called before the line that sets the value of `customParam2`:

```
var tree = Ext.create('CustomTree', {customParam2: 'someVal'});
```

So in order to make it work, you want to create your store when the constructor of `CustomTree` is called. But when working with components, it is best to override `initComponent` instead of the constructor. So here's how you should do it:

```
Ext.define('CustomTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.customtree',
    config: {
        customParam2: 'defaultVal'
    },
    // remove that
    // store: new CustomStore({customParam: this.customParam2'});

    // ... and put it in there:
    initComponent: function() {

        // creates the store after construct
        this.store = new CustomStore({customParam: this.customParam2});

        // call the superclass method *after* we created the store
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
    ...
});
```

As for `initConfig`, you have to call it in the constructor in order for you're config params to be applied. But in your case, you're extending from `Ext.data.Store` and `Ext.tree.Panel`, and their constructor already calls it, so you don't have to do it yourself.